# Activator.CreateInstance alternative overloads in .Net Standard

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I think I should be able to find something about this, but it seems I cannot.

I need to port a snippet of code that uses a missing overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` to .Net Standard 2.0.

```cs
string assembly = "My.Assembly";
string typeName = "My.Assembly.Something.MyType";
object newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, typeName).Unwrap();
```

How could I replace this single line of code?

Please keep in mind that the assembly is not guaranteed to be loaded when the code is called.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything too exciting, beyond actually loading the assembly and instantiating the type, so `Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.Load(assembly).GetType(typeName))` should be good enough. (Obviously this loads the assembly if not already loaded; so does the original call though.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert seem to work flawlessly. It seemed to be really easy but I couldn't come out with a simple enough solution. If you want, write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.